# I feel my plant looks sad. Does it need more light?

Tags: plant-health

My rubber plant which I bought just a week ago looks sad, does it need more light?[image]

Comment: If you repotted it after you got it home, has the pot its in got holes in the bottom, and did you use new potting soil? Why is the soil level so far below the rim of the pot? Where has it been in terms of light?

Answer (score 2):

It's generally thot that we humans project our feelings onto plants. Be happy around your plant. Encourage it. 
Then, take it out of the light. It's quite possible that it's sunburnt. Ficus elastica in its juvenile state is a shade loving plant. 
Another hint, the soil (why is everyone talking about my soil?) apoears dark. The perhaps greatest health threatening factor for house plants is overwatering. If you were to squeeze a handful of your soil, you should not get any water dripping. It's as if you were squeezing a sponge. Not dripping. Not hard and dry. Moist. Roots actually respirate, take in oxygen, and breathe. If they are submerged in water, they can't breathe.
There's a more basic question here. How big is your property? What are you going to do when your Ficus outgrows all your pots? Where will you plant this sidewalk destroying, driveway cracking, and house foundation destroyer?
If you've no plan, perhaps return the plant to the cosmos. Allow it to remake itself, discover another destiny. Perhaps it wants to become an  American pet. A greatly protected, pampered pet. More cherished than many other forms of sentient beings.
In summary, shade, ambient light. Reduce watering as well.

Answer (score 2):

More light should help. It may help to flatten the future leaves out. Rubber plants enjoy light. You may be giving it to much water when you water it, too. I've found mine seems to be happier with the same frequency of watering, but with less water when I do water it (it's a huge plant, maybe 7 feet tall, counting the container); I was giving it about a gallon, but I switched to much less. It seems to get fewer leaf blemishes that way. This could just be coincidence, though; it is in a new location, too.

They appreciate occasional fertilizer, too. I give mine 24-8-16 All Purpose Miracle Gro. I'm not sure that it's the ideal fertilizer, though, but it's helpful.

I agree with bamboo that the soil level is probably too far below the rim of the pot. I've never found that to be a good thing with any plant. It encourages damping off, and other issues, although I don't know that damping off would be an issue with a plant that big.